# Can't keep UILabel values displayed while changing UITabBar views

Tags: objective-c, uiview, ios8

Hey guys I am developing an app for a local games rental business here in my town, but I am having problems with values being kept displayed while I switch between views.

The app is based on a complete customized TabBar and the switching views implementation is working fine using this custom segue:

```
#import "CustomSegue.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation CustomSegue

- (void) perform {

ViewController *src = (ViewController *)self.sourceViewController;
UIViewController *dst = (UIViewController *) self.destinationViewController;

for(UIView *view in src.placeholderView.subviews){
    [view removeFromSuperview];
}

src.currentViewController = dst;
[src.placeholderView addSubview:dst.view];
}

@end
```

So, when the user hits the "Início" (Start) button, the app will trigger a counter. And when the user clicks the "Fim" (End) button the counter stops and a UIlabel displays the total time as you can check within the images below:

[image: App Initial State]
[image: Counter working after "Início"button is pressed]

The problem arises when I change the view to any other and later come back to the counter view. Instead of keeping displaying the the start time and the counter, it just shows me the initial state, zeroed start time and counter and it should display the start time and the counter still counting, as you can see within this image:

[image: App state after switching tabBar views]

It seems the the counter is still running in the background, this is what I think, but somehow it is not keeping it displayed when I change back a view to the counter one.

All variables are strong, I tried retain also but didn't work.

So any one could help me with this?

Comment: You're probably not coming back to the same instance of this controller, but instead, creating a new one. It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish with this custom segue. Segues are for moving between controllers, not adding and removing subviews.

Comment: Yes, after taking a look ate the custom segue code I noticed that too. But what I am doing is creating a placeholder for UIViews and as the user clicks on the corresponding button it will load to the placeholder the correct ViewController according to the segue identifier. Would you have a different approach as to the custom segue code?

Comment: I don't see why you're using a custom segue at all. Why not a modal presentation (without animation if you want)? When you add the view of one controller to the view of another, you really should be using the custom containment api and making the destination controller a child. In any case, for going back to a previous controller, you need to use an unwind segue, or go back in code.

Comment: Well, I tried doing modal presentation and the problem is that when the view is loaded it hides the TabBar.

Comment: I followed this tutorial; http://swiftiostutorials.com/tutorial-custom-tabbar-storyboard/

Comment: The problem with that tutorial, is that it doesn't go back to the previous controller. Every time you go from the first to the second and back again, it's creating a new instance, which is why you're having the problem you are. If you want to go back to the same instance, then don't use a segue. You need to create a controller that behaves like a UITabBarController, but with your own custom tab bar. It would need to have a viewControllers property that keeps a reference to all its controllers so they are not recreated every time you go back and forth.

Comment: You mean by creating a controller that behaves like a UITabBarController, subclassing a UITabBarController and creating it  programmatically?

Comment: I think you'll nee to subclass UIViewController, not UITabBarController, so you can add you own tab bar.

Answer (score 0):

finally I got it working using this Git project:
 https://github.com/mhaddl/MHCustomTabBarController